# Old session not destroyed with session_destroy in Chroom

Tags: php

When hitting the back button, and enter new values in my form which I store in a session array, the new session variables only appear when refreshing page I have tried all the solutions found on the internet but I still have the same issue and only in Chroom.

file1.php (contains the form) :

```
session_start(); 
$_SESSION = array(); 
session_destroy();
```

file2.php (Stores the from in a session)

```
    session_start(); 
    $_SESSION = array(); 
    session_destroy();
    session_start();
    header("Location: /file3.php");
    exit()
```

in file 3 where i display the result of the form, I have the old session variables instead of the new ones, i have to refresh my page to get the new values, how can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Where exactly in your code do you store the form ? I don't see it in `file2.php`, can you add it ? And can you also add a short version of `file3.php`, for us to test it if necessary ?

Comment: Keep session data on top of other session data those you want to display without page refresh. Thanks,